# FabricJS - Sepia Effect

Tags: matrix, fabricjs

Using fabricJS i am trying to add a sepia effect to my image but I am not happy with either the `sepia` or `sepia2` built in effects.

Below id a screenshot with the left image the Sepia2 effect and the right with what i hope to achieve:

[image]

Looking in the fabric.js file i can see the breakdown for how the effect is made (see below). I have spent the last hour changing values hoping they can change it to match the above but without understanding what number means what i cannot get a good match. Does anyone know the correct values for the sepia i am after?

```
applyTo: function(canvasEl) {
  var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d'),
      imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height),
      data = imageData.data,
      iLen = data.length, i, r, g, b;

  for (i = 0; i < iLen; i+=4) {
    r = data[i];
    g = data[i + 1];
    b = data[i + 2];

    data[i] = (r * 0.393 + g * 0.969 + b * 0.189 ) / 1.351;
    data[i + 1] = (r * 0.349 + g * 0.986 + b * 0.168 ) / 1.203;
    data[i + 2] = (r * 0.272 + g * 0.934 + b * 0.131 ) / 2.140;
  }

  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other sepia effects use a similar formula but without that trailing division.
So, taking the sepia2 filter;

Try changing these lines:

```
data[i] = (r * 0.393 + g * 0.969 + b * 0.189 ) / 1.351;
data[i + 1] = (r * 0.349 + g * 0.986 + b * 0.168 ) / 1.203;
data[i + 2] = (r * 0.272 + g * 0.934 + b * 0.131 ) / 2.140;
```

To simply:

```
data[i] = (r * 0.393 + g * 0.969 + b * 0.189 );
data[i + 1] = (r * 0.349 + g * 0.986 + b * 0.168 );
data[i + 2] = (r * 0.272 + g * 0.934 + b * 0.131 );
```

It is the closest I've been able to come to getting a 'recognizable' sepia effect.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Your sepia is spot on for me